# Implementing custom Curl authentication in Perl script

Tags: perl, curl, libcurl

I am building bot application trying to use perl script to implement the curl request, the issue I have is with Authorization.

The simple curl command is something like.

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer VM2CKBMXI3AVX2GMYPLBMYFRW3RCHYXS' \
  'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160722&q='
```

I preferred not to use system() calls from the Perl script as there will be  plenty of back and forth between the user and the bot.

I found this library 
http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.17/lib/WWW/Curl.pm

I was searching for setopt function in order to find out which params does it accept as my issue is where to put the Authorization param inside the command.
I found this link 
http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/curl/curl/perl/Curl_easy/easy.pm

My Script code for now it is like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
my $Authorization="Authorization: Bearer VM2CKBMXI3AVX2GMYPLBMYFRW3RCHYXS";

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160721&q=hello');

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;

# Looking at the results...
if ($retcode == 0) {
     print("Transfer went ok\n");
     my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     # judge result and next action based on $response_code
     print("Received response: $response_body\n");
} else {
     # Error code, type of error, error message
     print("An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
}
```

I just need to know which CURLOPT should I need to use in order to implement authorization. 
If you have any idea that will be great.

Thanks
Eran Gross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just  want to set the header "Authorization" the option is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1/dumprequest.php');
my @headers  = ("Authorization: keygoeshere", "X-Foo: Bah");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, \@headers);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
my $retcode = $curl->perform;
```

Gives:

```
GET dumprequest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: keygoeshere
X-Foo: Bah
```

But if you actually want to do HTTP authentication then you would use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` and `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`. See https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html for more info on options.